# Inner Join being ignored or improper usage?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have three tables

1. events: contains event id and some extra info
2. hosts: contains a host id, an event id, an original column, and an active column
3. going: contains a user id, an event id, and an active column which keeps track of status

Now an event can have multiple hosts and multiple going, what I'm trying to do is return all events and using `GROUP_CONCAT` and `INNER JOIN` to organize and return the hosts and those going and invited for a particular event in one JSON object.

However when using `INNER JOIN` to get all hosts and those going with the same event id as the event, it returns ALL entries in going and hosts that are active.

I'll get an output similar to

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "First Event",
        "going": "4",
        "hosts": "856400344377860,4",
        "invited": "1791375127753569",
        "original_host": "4,856400344377860"
    }
]
```

Here's my query

```
SELECT ev.id,
       ev.title,

GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN go.active = 1 THEN go.user_id END ORDER BY go.user_id) AS going, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT h.host_id) AS hosts, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN go.active = 2 THEN go.user_id END ORDER BY go.user_id) AS invited, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN h.original = 1 THEN h.host_id END ORDER BY h.host_id) AS original_host 

FROM events AS ev 
INNER JOIN going AS go ON ev.id = go.event_id 
INNER JOIN hosts AS h ON ev.id = h.event_id 

WHERE ev.active = 1 
AND h.active = 1 
AND (go.active = 1 OR go.active = 2) GROUP BY ev.id
```

The issue is that user number 4 is a host of a different event with a different id. Therefore he shouldn't be popping up in an event that he isn't hosting. Am I using `INNER JOIN` incorrectly or am I going this all wrong?

Please excuse any terrible query or database design, just starting out at this.

EDIT: There is an entry for user 4 going to the same event they're hosting. After deleting that entry in `going` then 4 no longer shows up in any of the fields  for first event just as it should be. This seemed to fix this but any idea why it's returning such unexpected results?

Comment: *any idea why this happened?* ...Any idea why *what* happened?  Why you inserted incorrect data into your database, or why, given incorrect data in the database, the query returned unexpected results?

Comment: Why the query returned unexpected results, sorry about that, should've been clearer.

Comment: I really don't see an explanation.  There's always a possibility of a bug if you're using an older version (`SELECT @@VERSION;`) but a reason for the group-by to incorrectly group is not readily apparent from the query.  I would have put all the join conditions in `ON` rather than `WHERE` but it should be logically equivalent.  You might try duplicating the issue at http://sqlfiddle.com and sharing.

Comment: you still need an answer for that mysql question, then un-delete it

Comment: I managed to scrape it together with some for loops by some miracle, thanks for your time though!

Comment: re-created a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33863572) if that helps