# printing numbers 1 to 100 with 10 numbers per line

Tags: mysql

In a re-print of a deleted question an hour ago,

> if I wanted to print out the numbers 1-100, with 10 numbers to a line
>   in the mysql shell, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally what i do is create a table (normally a temp table) and populate that with a stored procedure.

```
CREATE TABLE `numTable` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Id`)
)//

CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile(IN tableLimit INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE pointer INT DEFAULT tableLimit;
  WHILE pointer > 0 DO
    INSERT numTable VALUES (NULL);
    SET pointer = pointer - 1;
  END WHILE;
END//

CALL dowhile(100)//
```

now you may need to use `DELIMITER` but for the sake of consistency i have just copied what worked in SQL Fiddle by setting the Schema Delimiter to be `//` (forth button bellow the Schema Window)

then from there i then do a select of this table by giving each row a group id. since you want groups of 10 i have set the group to be multiples of 10 and then group by this group id using `GROUP_CONCAT` to make the rows.

```
select myRow 
from ( 
  SELECT group_concat(id SEPARATOR ', ') as `myRow`, CEIL(id/10) as `groupId`  
  FROM numTable group by `groupID`) as myTable;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80978/2)

since we don't want to show the group id i then make this a sub-select and only select my new rows. if you use this in something like PHP or C# to output the rows you can just do the one select since you don't have to output everything you get from a query result.

Answer (score 2):

Community wiki answer so as not to collect points. Edit at will.

```
select theAnswer
from
(   select @rn:=@rn+1 as rownum,
    concat(1+(@rn-1)*10,' ',2+(@rn-1)*10,' ',3+(@rn-1)*10,' ',4+(@rn-1)*10,' ',5+(@rn-1)*10,' ',
        6+(@rn-1)*10,' ',7+(@rn-1)*10,' ',8+(@rn-1)*10,' ',9+(@rn-1)*10,' ',10+(@rn-1)*10,' ') as theAnswer
    from (select @rn:=0) params1
    cross join (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9 union select 10) params2
) xDerived;

+---------------------------------+
| theAnswer                       |
+---------------------------------+
| 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10            |
| 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20   |
| 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30   |
| 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40   |
| 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50   |
| 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60   |
| 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70   |
| 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80   |
| 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90   |
| 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100  |
+---------------------------------+
```

The stuff inside of the `from ( )` is a derived table, and every derived table needs an alias, which is `xDerived`.

`@rn` is a row number variable. It gets initialized in the `params1` derived table. One row.

`params2` is another derived table, with rows 1 to 10 as values.

The `cross join` creates a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) (all permutations) of a 1x10 which results in 10 rows, with `@rn` getting incremented with each row.

As we only want one column of output, the outer wrapper does the final select for just one column to avoid outputting the row number column.

If one wanted to use a `WHILE DO` loop in mysql, one could use a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

In [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) with the [sequence plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sequence/):

```
select group_concat(seq order by seq separator ' ')
from seq_1_to_100
group by (seq-1) div 10;

| group_concat(seq order by seq separator ' ') |
|----------------------------------------------|
| 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10                         |
| 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20                |
| 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30                |
| 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40                |
| 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50                |
| 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60                |
| 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70                |
| 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80                |
| 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90                |
| 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100               |
```

A generic solution:

```
set @num_cols := 10;
set @max := 100;

select group_concat(seq order by seq separator ' ')
from seq_1_to_1000000
where seq <= @max
group by (seq-1) div @num_cols
order by min(seq);
```

If you want them all in one cell:

```
select group_concat(col separator '\n')
from (
    select group_concat(seq order by seq separator '\t') as col
    from seq_1_to_1000000
    where seq <= @max
    group by (seq-1) div @num_cols
) drv
```

Want to have columns?

```
set @num_cols := 7;
set @num_rows := 3;

set @sql := (
    concat('select ', (
        select group_concat('(seq-1)*', @num_cols, '+', seq, ' as c', seq)
        from seq_1_to_1000000
        where seq <= @num_cols
    ),' from seq_1_to_1000000 where seq<=', @num_rows)
);

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;

| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c6 | c7 |
|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
|  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |
|  8 |  9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |
```

If you don't have MariaDB with the sequence plugin, you can create a helper table with sequence numbers. Ask Drew how to do that :-)

Comment: If the RDBMS doesn't help you, you need to help RDBMS :-)